SQL Query to Find Top-Selling Brand in Each Territory Using ROW_NUMBER()
I'm trying to write an SQL query to find the top-selling brand in each territory from my sales data. I am using three tables:
map_customer_territory, fct_customer_sales, and dim_product.
I want to join these tables and use the ROW_NUMBER() function to rank the brands within each territory based on their total sales.
Here is the query I have written so far:
WITH cte1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        mp.territory_id, 
        dp.prod_brand,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mp.territory_id ORDER BY SUM(fc.order_value) DESC) AS rnk
    FROM 
        map_customer_territory mp 
    JOIN 
        fct_customer_sales fc ON mp.cust_id = fc.cust_id
    JOIN 
        dim_product dp ON fc.prod_sku_id = dp.prod_sku_id
    GROUP BY 
        mp.territory_id, dp.prod_brand
)
SELECT 
    territory_id, 
    prod_brand
FROM 
    cte1
WHERE 
    rnk = 1
ORDER BY 
    territory_id ASC;

However, the query does not seem to produce the correct results. I want to ensure that the output contains the top-selling brand for each territory, sorted by territory_id in ascending order.
Expected output
territory_id & prod_brand

Actual output
The query does not return the expected top-selling brands.
Question
How can I modify my query to correctly find the top-selling brand in each territory? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

You need to provide an example of your current output, and an example of your desired output, to allow us to be able to help you.

Also sample input data for all relevant tables please.

Why should I "tag my RDBMS"? - please add a tag to specify whether you're using mysql, postgresql, sql-server, oracle or db2 - or something else entirely.
